# Weird Rails migration behaviour - repeating add_references commands and failing with ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::DuplicateColumn

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, rails-migrations

I'm running Rails 5.2.4.4 and have found the strangest behaviour when I have two add_references listed in my users migration. Even though they are unique lines for different table references, the output shows the first one repeated, then failing due to duplicate column. If I switch the statements around, it simply causes the other add_reference to repeat and fail:

Migration:

```
def change
  add_column :users, :first_name, :string
  add_column :users, :last_name, :string
  add_column :users, :authentication_token, :string
  add_column :users, :location, :string
  add_column :users, :is_admin, :boolean, default: false
  add_column :users, :account_active, :boolean, default: true
end

add_reference :users, :tagging, type: :uuid, foreign_key: true, null: true
add_reference :users, :tenant, type: :uuid, foreign_key: true

add_index :users, :created_at
```

Results in this error:

```
-- add_reference(:users, :tagging, {:type=>:uuid, :foreign_key=>true, :null=>true})
-- add_reference(:users, :tagging, {:type=>:uuid, :foreign_key=>true, :null=>true})
rails aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::DuplicateColumn: ERROR:  column "tagging_id" of relation "users" already exists
```

If I switch the add_references columns around:

```
  add_reference :users, :tenant, type: :uuid, foreign_key: true
  add_reference :users, :tagging, type: :uuid, foreign_key: true, null: true
```

I instead get:

```
-- add_reference(:users, :tenant, {:type=>:uuid, :foreign_key=>true})
-- add_reference(:users, :tenant, {:type=>:uuid, :foreign_key=>true})
rails aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::DuplicateColumn: ERROR:  column "tenant_id" of relation "users" already exists
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue...

I had placed the add_references code outside the def change block.

Shifted it and all fixed.